# Call issue with Freeswitch

Tags: configuration, voip, freeswitch

I am testing the following with Freeswitch and different devices
(nokia n900, nokia e60, ekiga) and have similar results between them.

On the Freeswitch server (1.0.4 in multi-tenant mode) I have several
user profiles for a domain, e.g. 1000, 1001 for host.com
The user are authenticated correctly and calls can be placed. When I
place a call from a device registered as

1001@host.com

to

1002@host.com

it will show up at the other end (1002) as

1001@12.34.56.78

I would expect this call to show up as 1001@host.com. The IP address
is the one of from the Freeswitch server. Because of this, the calls
are not correctly recognized by the address book on certain devices.
Can the he domain FQDN of the callers domain/account be used, instead
of the IP address of the server in the SIP uri?

Comment: Please use more specific title for question.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be divergent ideas on how to set up multi-tenant with FreeSwitch, so maybe link to any documentation you followed, or provide a stripped-down example of the xml or dialplan script(s).

I'm pretty sure this works fine for us, but I can't say for sure exactly why.  Maybe Reverse DNS will help, but I don't think we always have that.  This may have more to do with the user than the domain.